# Assign an array of objects to another object's key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I am working on a Q&A app in Laravel. Here, I have two migrations or database tables, one is question_bank and second is answer_choices. There is one to many relation between question and answers table. While retrieving a question, I want to retrieve all of the answers which are related with this question.

For this i wrote a method:

```
public function getQuestion($id){
    $question=QuestionBank::find($id);
    $answers=AnswerBank::where('question_id','=',$id)->get();
    $question->answers=$answers;
        return Response::json($question);
}
```

The answer_choices migration is :

```
class AnswerChoices extends Migration {
public function up()
{
Schema::create('answer_choices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();
        $table->mediumtext('answer_text');
        $table->boolean('correct')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('question_bank');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('answer_choices');
}
}
```

And the model is :

```
<?php

class AnswerBank extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];
protected $table = "answer_choices";
}
```

Question model is

```
<?php

class QuestionBank extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];
protected $table = "question_bank";
}
```

I expected i will get result as `question.answers:[{},{},{}]`
but on client side I am getting it like `"question.answers":{}` as a blank object. When I return only `$answers`, it shows all the answer objects in the array like `[{},{},{]]`.

How can I get the answers objects as an array of objects in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Given by Creator is totally fine just having a small mistake. Corect that and your code will be run.
Change this function

```
public function answers(){

    return $this->HasMany('AnswerBank','id','question_id');

 }
```

to

```
public function answers(){

    return $this->HasMany('AnswerBank','question_id','id');

}
```

Replace `question_id` with `id` and it will work.
And return question object with answers like this

```
public function getQuestion($id){  
    $answers=QuestionBank::with('answers')->find($id);
    return Response::json($answers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is one to many relation between question and answers table. While retrieving a question, I want to retrieve all of the answers which are related with this question

Since you already have a relationship defined, you just need to [Eager Load](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) the relationship when you get the questions, and it will include the answers automatically

```
public function getQuestion($id){
    $question=QuestionBank::with('answers')->find($id);
    return Response::json($question);
}
```

Comment: what is `with('answers')` here?

Comment: Thats how you Eager Load. Check the link to the official docs I provided.

Comment: okay, means `answers` in $question=QuestionBank::with('answers')->find($id); is the name of migration. isn't it?

Comment: 'answers' is your relationship between question and answers table. You said you setup the relationship already.

Comment: `Schema::create('answer_choices', function (Blueprint $table) {  
            $table->increments('id');  
            $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();  
            $table->mediumtext('answer_text');  
            $table->boolean('correct')->nullable();  

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('question_bank');
                  });`
This is the table or migration

Comment: Model name is AnswerBank. the relationship field name is question_id, the key i required is answers.

Comment: Post your question model as well please

Comment: i have already posted the model in the Question. are u asking to post the question migration?

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't declared any relation in model. It could be the reason for null output. Alright in you QuestionBank first declare a relation and then call

```
// in model QuestionBank 


public function answers(){

  return $this->HasMany('AnswerBank','id','question_id');

 } 

 // In AnswerBank Model use this

  public function question(){

  return  $this->BelongsTo('QuestionBank');

   }
```

Now you can get all answers to your question by Calling:

```
public function getQuestion($id){
  $answers=QuestionBank::with('answers')->find($id);
  return Response::json($answers);
 }
```

Comment: it is working but returning a blank array for answers

Comment: have you declared HasMany in your QuestionBank Model?

Comment: Still it is returning empty array. but if i change `return $this->HasMany('AnswerBank','id','question_id');` to `return $this->belongsTo('AnswerBank','id','question_id');` it return a single answer as an object not array of objects or answers

Comment: can you show you both table attribute here? according to you one question has many answers . So QuestionBank ->has many AnswerBank. IF this is the case above answer should be working.

Comment: mysql> desc answer_choices; | Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra | | id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment | `| question_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL |` | | answer_text | mediumtext | NO | | NULL | | | correct | tinyint(1) | YES | | NULL | | | created_at | timestamp | NO | | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | | | updated_at | timestamp | NO | | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | |

Comment: `| question_id | int(10) unsigned | NO | MUL |` NULL this is the relationship field in the table answer_choice